# Collectors.toMap() giving NPE Internally

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to collect data as map in stream execution.

To make sure I am not having any duplicates I am using `merger function` but ending up having NPE.

See code snippet

```
streamableList().stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(it-> nonNull(it.getKeyHere()))
    .collect(toMap(it -> it.getKeyHere(),
            it -> it.getValueHere(), (a1, a2) -> a1));
```

See exception below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1216)
        at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)....
.....and further calls of written code....
```

Can anyone suggest why it is failing while collecting and how to resolve?

Comment: What is `streamableList()`

Comment: Can you please post some data to simulate```streamableList()```? And also, as @YCF_L asks, the type of the list returned.

Comment: Is it possible that `it.getValueHere()` returns null?

Comment: As long as you don't add a minimal, verifiable example we are not able to help

Comment: filter(Objects::nonNull) is enough I guess no need of other filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap::merge` throws if any value is null.

```
@Override
public V merge(K key, V value,
               BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException(); //here
```

So `getValueHere` must return `null`. You only do a null check against the item and the key, never the value.

You can add another filter, or make sure your class doesn't contain null values.

```
.filter(it -> Objects.nonNull(it.getValueHere()))
```

Comment: or `.filter(it-> nonNull(it.getKeyHere()) && nonNull(it.getValueHere()))`

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

I just looked up the `HashMap` code from Java 1.8. Here is the snippet. It throws an NPE when the value to be merged is passed as `null`.

```
@Override
public V merge(K key, V value,
               BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
```

### Original Post

Yes, as @Pshema pointed out, when `it.getValueHere()` returns `null`, we get this error. Here is a reproduction.

```
public class NPECollectorsToMap{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Map<String, String> map = doThis();
        System.out.println( map );
    }

    private static Map<String, String> doThis() {
        return streamableList().stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(it-> nonNull(it.getKeyHere()))
        .collect(toMap(it -> it.getKeyHere(),
                it -> it.getValueHere(), (a1, a2) -> a1));
    }

    private static List<It> streamableList(){
        List<It> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add( new It( "a", null ) );
        return list;
    }

    private static class It{
        private String keyHere;
        public It( String keyHere, String valueHere ){
            super();
            this.keyHere = keyHere;
            this.valueHere = valueHere;
        }
        private String valueHere;
        public String getKeyHere(){ return keyHere; }
        public void setKeyHere( String keyHere ){ this.keyHere = keyHere; }
        public String getValueHere(){ return valueHere; }
        public void setValueHere( String valueHere ){ this.valueHere = valueHere; }

    }
}
```